# How can I line up a multi row/column form?

Tags: css

I want to be able to line up the labels correctly in columns, so that varying length/type input fields always line up.  The labels are always formatted to the same length.

Also, I could do with being able to omit rows in come of the columns if required.  I've achieved this by having a `&nbsp;` within the cols div.

What I've done works; however, it 'feels' as though it's a fudge, and I think there should be better ways of achieving this.

Cheers.

```
<div id="divAddInputFields">
    <fieldset id="fsAddInputFields" class="inputFieldSet">
        <div id="divFsAddCol1">
            <div id="divFsAddCol1Row1">
                <label id="lblGenCode" for="wsGenCode">Gen Code</label><input type="text" class="String02" name="wsGenCode" id="wsGenCode" />
            </div>
            <div id="divFsAddCol1Row2">
                <label id="lblRelNote" for="wsRelNote">Rel Note</label><input type="text" class="String12" name="wsRelNote" id="wsRelNote" />
            </div>
            <div id="divFsAddCol1Row3">
                <label id="lblQuantity" for="wsQuantity">Quantity</label><input type="text" class="Number7_0" name="wsQuantity" id="wsQuantity" />
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="divFsAddCol1Row1">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        <div id="divFsAddCol2">
            <div id="divFsAddCol2Row1">
                <label id="lblCofC" for="wsCofC">C of C</label><input type="text" class="String12" name="wsCofC" id="wsCofC" />
            </div>
            <div id="divFsAddCol2Row2">
                <label id="lblComp" for="wsComp">Comp</label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="wsComp" id="wsComp" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Page specific css (in an external file.....).

```
#divAddInputFields  {width:460px;       margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; height:160px; overflow:auto;    float:left; }
#divFsAddCol1       {width:220px;       margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; height:140px; overflow:auto;    float:left; }
#divFsAddCol2       {width:220px;       margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; height:140px; overflow:auto;    float:left; }
```

Css from a library

```
.inputFieldSet 
{   padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;    
    border:none;}

.label, .inputFieldSet label {
    height:15px;
    width:80px; 
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid black; 
    padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;    
    background-color:#66cdaa;   
    vertical-align:top; 
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px 1px 1px 3px;
    font-size:10px;
}

.inputFieldSet input {
    height:15px;
    padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;    
    border:1px solid grey;  
    vertical-align:top;
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    margin:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.inputFieldSet input[type="submit"] {
    padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;    
    vertical-align:top;
    height:20px;
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    margin:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.inputFieldSet input[type="checkbox"]  {
    padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;    
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.inputFieldSet select {
    padding:1px 0px 1px 2px;    
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    margin:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `<table>` for this if you can.

Tables are intended for displaying tabular data like this.

They (correctly) got a bad rap for being used for doing HTML design layout.

But for tablular data like this I would use one.
You'll obviously be able to take care of alignment issues much easier.

Comment: I've been using tables on nearly everything I've done in the past, but from what I've been reading the 'view' seems to be that forms 'should' be designed with CSS.  I was hoping to see how feasible it is to do this, or if it's too much work for little benefit. Cheers.